# Issue by adding mschart to the windows azure application with WCF service

Tags: wcf, visual-studio, azure, mschart

I have a very strange issue. I am not able to run a windows azure application which has a WCF service and mschart in it.
Following are the steps to reproduce the error:
1) Create a new windowsazureapplication with a blank asp.net webrole
2) Now add a new WCfService
3) run to check it runs ok
4) now in one of the pages include mschart, and open the design of the page to make sure the webconfig is changed to use the mschart.
5) now try to run the project.
I am getting error message like this one:
[image]

Is this a problem with windows azure or am I doing somthing wrong?
FYI: This is not my first project on windows azure.

Comment: I am able to see the problem exactly as your described above. I am digging it further now..

Comment: I am able to solve this problem by setting both WCF and ASP.NET web role properties to 3.5 > Save and then changing again back to 4.0. Afte that I could launch/debug the same application in Compute Emulator without any error. Try and let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the solution. You just need to add the following in your web.config inside system.webserver section:

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
```

The final system.webserver looks like as below:

```
<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  <handlers>
   <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
    <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
    path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </handlers>
 <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
```

After adding above, I did not see the problem at all.

Comment: Thanks alot!! you are a life saver. I had the same line in webconfig but in another <system.webserver> section.

Comment: As you are from Microsoft, is this an issue or is it meant to be this way only?